# kafka "fetch offset out of range for partition resetting offset", but it is actually not out of range

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In a java program, it receives kafka message like this:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = AlarmKafkaConfig.alarmTopic))
@Component
public class AlarmConsumer {
    @KafkaHandler
    public void handler(List<String> records, Acknowledgment ack) {
         try { // do things.
         } catch (Throwable e) { // logs.
         } finally {
              ack.acknowledge();
         }
    }
}
```

And this is given in kafka server:

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --all-groups --describe

GROUP                   TOPIC                             PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                                             HOST            CLIENT-ID
alarm-property-file push_warn_topic_debug 0          2               11              9               consumer-alarm-property-file-1-01600f36-312f-4b5d-8489-e74338866748 /172.21.9.20    consumer-alarm-property-file-1
```

And this is error:

```
INFO KafkaMessageListenerContainer: alarm-property-file: partitions assigned: [push_warn_topic_debug-0]
DEBUG onSuccess [Consumer clientId=consumer-alarm-property-file-1, groupId=alarm-property-file] Fetch READ_UNCOMMITTED at offset 2 for partition push_warn_topic_debug-0 returned fetch data (error=OFFSET_OUT_OF_RANGE, highWaterMark=-1, lastStableOffset = -1, logStartOffset = -1, preferredReadReplica = absent, abortedTransactions = null, recordsSizeInBytes=0)
INFO initializeCompletedFetch: [Consumer clientId=consumer-alarm-property-file-1, groupId=alarm-property-file] Fetch offset 2 is out of range for partition push_warn_topic_debug-0, resetting offset
INFO maybeSeekUnvalidated: Consumer clientId=consumer-alarm-property-file-1, groupId=alarm-property-file] Resetting offset for partition push_warn_topic_debug-0 to offset 11.
```

From above runtime log, kafka client first fetch current offset 2 from server, and then it somehow thinks it is out of range, then it trys to reset offset to 11.
2 is obvious not out of range, compare with 11. And this confuses me. From server side, I can see that its current offset is 2, and its latest offset is 11. Now the server has only one kafka client.

Comment: After more digging, I believe they are deleted in kafka server, because of `log.retention.hours` in server.properties